# When uploading code to the ESP32 Cam I'm getting an error

Tags: arduino, esp32

I'm getting this error when I upload code to my ESP32 Cam. Even if I uninstalled and reinstalled the Arduino IDE, it's still giving me the same error:

```
A fatal error occurred: Could not open COM9, the port doesn't exist
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 2
```

Reinstalling Arduino, updating the software and disconnecting the port pin.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the USB cable is broken (maybe try it with other devices ?), or that the COM9 port is already used by an other program.

This error seems to be more related to the `ESP32 Cam` than the arduino IDE.

I've encountered this issue before, and resolved it like that.

If the problem is still there, try others usb cables, and make sure that they can transmit data and not only power.